# Smooth scrolling not so smooth

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to create a smooth scrolling with plain js. I tried it with typical animation timing using this:

```
function animate(x) {
    var start = new Date();
    var id = setInterval(function () {
        var timepassed = new Date() - start;
        var progress = timepassed / x.duration;
        if (progress > 1) {
            progress = 1;
        }
        var delta = x.delta(progress);
        x.step(delta);
        if (progress == 1) {
            clearInterval(id);
        }
    }, x.delay);
}
```

After that I'm measuring `offsetTop` elements and using `scrollTo()` to get there using
`window.scrollTo(0, delta * to.offsetTop);`
where `delta` is returned progress of time. But the problem is that it does not seem so smooth to my eyes. Am I missing some important information about animation?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Trolstover/4e9LbLr1/)

(using else if to find out which way the anmiation should go - at least for now)

Comment: The best way to make animation smooth is to use the `requestAnimationFrame()` function to ensure that your animations happen on a frame redraw - this synchronises with natural screen refreshes and should create smoother motion. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: @trolkura Did your question get answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two aspects to your issue here:

- Performance
- Perceived smoothness

---

**Performance**

In your code you would gain performance by using [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of `setInterval()`. There is also a nice [article for transitioning to the new method](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/animating-with-javascript-from-setinterval-to-requestanimationframe/) on mozilla or an [in-depth article by Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/). As a note: because you want to achieve 60fps, your code shouldn't take longer than 16ms calculation time.

**Perceived animation smoothness *& Easing***

For the second issue: your animation is linear, thus it's boring.
When (if you ever did) you use an animation-library or jQuery for some animation, you can always specify which timing-function the animation should use. These are for example 'ease-in', 'ease-out', and so on. You can implement these in your [function through some math](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/04/quick-look-math-animations-javascript/). There are many tools in the web which [visualize these easing-equotations](http://gizma.com/easing/) in [different ways](http://easings.net/).

If you are now hungry for more input, check out [Robert Penner's Easing Page](http://robertpenner.com/easing/).

Last, but not least, take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dezinezync/5487119#file-scroll-easing-js), which also provides JavaScript-Implementation of the different easing functions - oh and also another possible solution in Vanilla JS ;)

p.s. just for demonstration, [your code with a little ease](http://jsfiddle.net/4e9LbLr1/4/)

Answer (score 1):

To branch on @Sebastian's answer here is a real quick demo of your code using     `window.requestAnimationFrame();`

http://jsfiddle.net/xerxesnoble/e53qm15L/4/

More than just that, here is another simple way (using jQuery) to have a smooth scroll in your code:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/